# How can I get the current url protocol in the MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

This method returns the domain and port:

```
public Uri BuildUrl()
{
    Uri domain = new Uri(Request.GetDisplayUrl());
    return new Uri(domain.Host + (domain.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + domain.Port));
}
```

But it does not include the "http://" or "https://" part. How can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the protocol from `Scheme` property of `Uri`.

```
public Uri BuildUrl()
{
    Uri domain = new Uri(Request.GetDisplayUrl());
    return new Uri(domain.Scheme + "://" + domain.Host + (domain.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + domain.Port));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is [`Scheme` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.scheme?view=netframework-4.8)

then you can use `UriBuilder`

```
var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(domain.Host)
{
    Scheme = domain.Scheme,
    Port = domain.IsDefaultPort ? -1 : domain.Port
};

return uriBuilder.Uri;
```

but your method doesn't make any sense, why not use

```
public Uri BuildUrl() => new Uri(Request.GetDisplayUrl());
```